# JSP file doesn't see my CSS file

Tags: java, html, css, jsp, web-applications

I am experiencing problems with JSP files.

My `index.jsp` file doesn't see the CSS file (which is in the correct location). Screenshot:

[image: index.jsp]

I noticed that when I open the code viewer in Chrome, the browser sees my CSS, but with the same HTML code that I wrote in the `index.jsp` file:

[image: Chrome screenshot]

All others JSP files have same problem. Please advise.

Comment: are you using maven? are you including your css files in the build resources?

Comment: I'm using maven but i didnt included resources in pom.xml. But even if do that it still does'n work [pom.xml](http://qs.lc/dnld5) may be  i included in wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

You need change your link code like this :

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/main.css">
```

Not just `contextPath` | add `pageContext.request.contextPath` to access it